# Express.js http call inside route doesn't update variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, express, request

I'm building a REST api on top of express.js. I am having trouble updating variables inside my routes.

Example:

I'm calling `app.get("/wp/page/create/:id", function(req, res)`

Inside this route I start by calling a http request using `request-promise` library. The response of this call I use in a nested http call.

I use a global variable for the headers for the nested call, and it's to the header a i need to make changes by using the `etag` variable.

Code:

```
global.postHeaders = headers;
postHeaders['X-HTTP-Method'] = "MERGE";
postHeaders['Content-Type'] = 'application/json;odata=verbose';
postHeaders['X-RequestDigest'] = spContext;

request.get({
url: "xxx",
headers: headers,
json: true
}).then(function(response) {
    var etag = response.d.__metadata.etag
    postHeaders['If-Match'] = etag;

    request.post({
       url: "xxx",
       type: "POST",
       body: data,
       headers: postHeaders,
       json: true
       }).then(function(data) {
          res.send(data).end()
          console.log("All done!");
      })
})
```

When i start the server up and enter the route everything works fine. When i when try to hit it again the `etag` variables is still the same, even though it should be updated.

If I restart the server it works the again on the first attempt but fails on the second/third.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have resolved the issues. The simple solution was to clear the headers containing the variable.

```
global.postHeaders = headers;
postHeaders['X-HTTP-Method'] = "MERGE";
postHeaders['Content-Type'] = 'application/json;odata=verbose';
postHeaders['X-RequestDigest'] = spContext;

request.get({
 url: "xxx",
 headers: headers,
 json: true
 }).then(function(response) {
var etag = response.d.__metadata.etag
postHeaders['If-Match'] = etag;

   request.post({
     url: "xxx",
     type: "POST",
     body: data,
     headers: postHeaders,
     json: true
     }).then(function(data) {
      postHeaders['If-Match'] = "";
      res.send(data).end()
      console.log("All done!");
  })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

postHeaders is a global variable. is headers in `global.postHeaders = headers;` also a global varaible ? Whatever you are trying to do here is grossly wrong. postHeaders variable will be shared across multiple request. so you will hit a scenario where `postHeaders['If-Match']` value might be empty string or the etag .

Try this instead of the first line
`var postHeaders = Object.assign({}, headers);`

Not sure what you are trying, but at-least this statement will subside the huge error in the code. This will create a new header object for each request.